# jQuery code is hiding all content inside my div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("ul.accordion-section-content li[id*='layers-builder'] button.add-new-widget").click(function() {
    $("#available-widgets-list div:not([id*='layers-widget'])").css('display','none');
  });
});
```

The idea is, when i click a button that contains the class "layers-builder", all divs in "available-widgets-list" that DO NOT contain the class "layers-widget" are hidden.

The problem I'm facing is that using this code also hides all the divs inside "layers-widget" (as not all of them have "layers-widget" in the id.

for example, here is a mockup markup:

```
<div id="some-id">
...
</div>

<div id="this-layers-widget-89">
    <div id="hello"></div>
    <div id="yes"></div>
</div>
```

In the above example, the first div "some-id" would be hidden, along with all the child divs inside "this-layers-widget-89"

How can I make it so that all the content within the div containing "layers-widget" still shows?

Comment: it's probably a css hierarchy problem try `"#available-widgets-list > div:not([id*='layers-widget'])" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ">" operator specifies that the `div` must be a direct child of `#available-widgets-list`:

```
$("#available-widgets-list > div:not([id*='layers-widget'])").css('display','none');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a class instead of relying on finding parts of `some-id` but this will work also work: `$('[id*="some-id"]')`;

You should also be using jquery's built in `hide()`method instead of `css('display', 'none')`. They do literally the exact same thing but using the built in methods is more readable.